# OSB 11g Streaming with WCF doesn't work

Tags: http-streaming, osb, oracle-service-bus

I'm trying to use the OSB 11g to stream large data to .NET WCF.
I use .NET client and server to check this feature.
I created a proxy which make a service callout to the WCF on the .NET server 
but when tracing the streaming i find that the OSB buffers all the stream coming from the client into memory and then send it to the .NET WCF.
I guess i configured the proxy correctly with content streaming feature.
by the way i'm running the OSB over linux Red Hat 5.5.
Can any one please share is expirience working with WCF??
Can someone share his Streaming definition in the Proxy/Business services?